# Deploy different folders to different heroku apps with Travis CI

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rest, heroku, travis-ci

In the last few days I tried to setup Travis CI for one of my Webapp’s which are in development.

I structured my app into three submodules. This submodules are in three different directories inside my Repository.

Now I want to deploy each of that submodules to a different Heroku instance.

Project folder structure:

Root Folder 
- Module 1 (React app) 
  - build 
- Module 2 (React app)
  - build 
- Module 3 (NodeJS, Express Rest API)

Two of the three submodules are React Apps created with create-react-app. The build process works fine on Travis. After adding

the “skip_cleanup: true” flag into my config I find my exported React app inside of the build folder.

Now I want to deploy the content of  “Module 1 (React app)/build/*” and “Module 2 (React app)/build/*” to two different Heroku instances.

The content of “Module 3 (NodeJS, Express Rest API)/*” goes into a third Heroku instance.

This is my theoretic attempt.

I setup my .travis.yml and ended with something like this:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
- stable
cache:
  yarn: true
  directories:
  - node_modules
script:
- yarn run test
after_success:
- yarn run build
deploy:
  provider: heroku
  api_key: api_key
 app: teamx-administration
  file_glob: true
  file: teamx-administration/build/*
  skip_cleanup: true
  on:
    repo: lusu007/TeamXWebApp
    branch: develop
```

The problem with this configuration is that Travis deploys the whole app with all 3 modules to the teamx-administration app on Heroku and not only the folder I specified with the “file: teamx-administration/build/*” flag.
I don’t know how I have to configure Travis to do that for me.

I hope someone of your team can help me with this problem.

Furthermore I asked me the question how can deploy the other two modules of my Webapp too. Can I just add another provider block for Heroku with all needed informations into my .travis.yml?

Also after some time my Heroku API which I get from the “heroku auth:token” expired after just a few hours. How can I get a key which has a longer expiration time, because it is very disappointing to get a new key after a few hours.

I’m looking forward to hearing something from you.

Comment: Have you considered using a bash script, possibly even one for each part, to deploy the pieces to heroku? You should be able to pass some of your environment variables such as api_key to them (if necessary -- may already be passed on; be sure to check) pretty simply, and it would allow you full control over which parts go where.

Comment: @l3l_aze I fixed this problem about two weeks after this post.My solution was: [.travis.yml](https://pastebin.com/cbSbf9V0)

Comment: Ahh, nice! I didn't know there could be multiple entries for deploy, lol. Thank you for sharing :)